# UX designer for internal tools in a small firm

Tags: ux-designer

I work as a developer in a small financial firm (< 40 people), and we have a whole bunch of tools that we develop internally (spreadsheets, c# apps, web apps) that are not really integrated and working well with each other.

And so people interact a lot with emails and copy pasting stuff, the usual internal mess and so on.

We *think* that we would need a UX designer to take what we have and re-think the whole picture and integrate the various tools we have into a single large application framework that would allow us to streamline the workflow of our internal users. (I don't know exactly how that would work, but something like a blend of interactive data visualizations, and internal social blogging/chatting to share them, save them, and comment on them).

Now, the problem is where do we find a guy like that? Are we looking for a UX designer at all? For a UI developer? Does this role even exist? Are we too small? Do UX people despise designing internal tools? And are there online communities that I could chat to ask these kinds of question?

Apologies if this isn't the right place to post, I'd be happy to know where to post this if that's the case.

Thanks

Comment: I do something similar actually, and trust me when I say you do not want to put everything in a single large UI.

Comment: While I can understand this as being a genuine UX related issue, the question doesn't fit into the format of this site, and so I have to close it.

Comment: @JohnGB: I understand, no problem. Would you know a more appropriate forum for this kind of questions?

Comment: @d--b It's probably better suited to a discussion forum, or something like Quora.  Typically I would just ask in the UX chat room though, but it takes a while to get a reply there.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, a small company like this needs someone who is an "all round" developer. You will want someone who can design UIs *and* actually build the prototypes. This is a much more enjoyable job compared to one where you are a small cog in a large machine. If you advertise for this kind of role you will hopefully attract someone who enjoys this type of challenge.